org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500 in Appium Java
I'm getting the error while running  appium script to open a URL in chrome browser. Below is the code snippet configured to start appium server. Server gets started but end up throwing the error mentioned.
Have dowgraded the chrome browser version from 131. to 118 in mobile, but still the same error.
Appreciate any inputs to resolve this issue.
builder = new AppiumServiceBuilder();
            builder.withAppiumJS(new File("C:\\Users\\sudha\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\appium\\build\\lib\\main.js"))
            .withIPAddress("127.0.0.1")
            .usingPort(4723)
            .withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(20)).build().start();
        service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(builder);
        service.start();
        System.out.println("Appium Url:" + service.getUrl());
        System.out.println("Is Server Running:" + service.isRunning());
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        
        
    UiAutomator2Options options = new UiAutomator2Options();
    options.setPlatformName("Android");
    options.setPlatformVersion("14.0");
    options.setAutomationName("UiAutomator2");
    options.setDeviceName("RZCWA1JJM5L");
    options.noReset();
    options.withBrowserName("chrome");
    driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/"),options);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(100));
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/");

Error log
[38;5;229m[ADB][0m Running 'C:\Users\sudha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s RZCWA1JJM5L shell wm dismiss-keyguard'
[38;5;171m[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@cf8b (9fe4b1ad)][0m Starting a chrome-based browser session
[38;5;171m[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@cf8b (9fe4b1ad)][0m A port was not given, using random free port: 61895
[38;5;171m[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@cf8b (9fe4b1ad)][0m Automated Chromedriver download is disabled. Use 'chromedriver_autodownload' server feature to enable it
[38;5;171m[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@cf8b (9fe4b1ad)][0m Precalculated Chromedriver capabilities: {
[38;5;171m[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@cf8b (9fe4b1ad)][0m   "androidPackage": "com.android.chrome",
[38;5;171m[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@cf8b (9fe4b1ad)][0m   "androidDeviceSerial": "RZCWA1JJM5L"
[38;5;171m[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@cf8b (9fe4b1ad)][0m }
[38;5;171m[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@cf8b (9fe4b1ad)][0m Before starting chromedriver, androidPackage is 'com.android.chrome'
[38;5;160m[Chromedriver@3270][0m Changed state to 'starting'
[38;5;160m[Chromedriver@3270][0m Using the static Chromedriver->Chrome mapping
[38;5;160m[Chromedriver@3270][0m The most recent known Chrome version: 121.0.6167
[38;5;160m[Chromedriver@3270][0m Found 1 executable in 'C:\Users\sudha\.appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-driver\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\chromedriver\win'
[38;5;160m[Chromedriver@3270][0m The following Chromedriver executables were found:
[38;5;160m[Chromedriver@3270][0m     'C:\Users\sudha\.appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-driver\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\chromedriver\win\chromedriver-win64_v121.0.6167.85.exe' (version '121.0.6167.85', minimum Chrome version '121.0.6167')
[38;5;229m[ADB][0m Getting package info for 'com.android.chrome'
[38;5;229m[ADB][0m Running 'C:\Users\sudha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s RZCWA1JJM5L shell dumpsys package com.android.chrome'
[38;5;160m[Chromedriver@3270][0m Found Chrome bundle 'com.android.chrome' version '118.0.5993'
[38;5;160m[Chromedriver@3270][0m Error: No Chromedriver found that can automate Chrome '118.0.5993'. You could also try to enable automated chromedrivers download as a possible workaround.
[38;5;160m[Chromedriver@3270][0m     at Chromedriver.getCompatibleChromedriver (C:\Users\sudha\.appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-driver\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\lib\chromedriver.js:457:15)
[38;5;160m[Chromedriver@3270][0m     at Chromedriver.initChromedriverPath (C:\Users\sudha\.appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-driver\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\lib\chromedriver.js:489:11)
[38;5;160m[Chromedriver@3270][0m     at Chromedriver.start (C:\Users\sudha\.appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-driver\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\lib\chromedriver.js:609:32)
[38;5;160m[Chromedriver@3270][0m     at AndroidUiautomator2Driver.setupNewChromedriver (C:\Users\sudha\.appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-driver\node_modules\appium-android-driver\lib\commands\context\helpers.js:745:3)
[38;5;160m[Chromedriver@3270][0m     at AndroidUiautomator2Driver.startChromeSession (C:\Users\sudha\.appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-driver\node_modules\appium-android-driver\lib\commands\context\exports.js:346:23)
[38;5;160m[Chromedriver@3270][0m     at AndroidUiautomator2Driver.performSessionPostExecSetup (C:\Users\sudha\.appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-driver\lib\driver.ts:647:7)
[38;5;160m[Chromedriver@3270][0m     at AndroidUiautomator2Driver.startUiAutomator2Session (C:\Users\sudha\.appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-driver\lib\driver.ts:697:5)
[38;5;160m[Chromedriver@3270][0m     at AndroidUiautomator2Driver.createSession (C:\Users\sudha\.appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-driver\lib\driver.ts:419:22)
[38;5;160m[Chromedriver@3270][0m     at AppiumDriver.createSession (C:\Users\sudha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\lib\appium.js:740:35)
[38;5;160m[Chromedriver@3270][0m No Chromedriver found that can automate Chrome '118.0.5993'. You could also try to enable automated chromedrivers download as a possible workaround.
[38;5;171m[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@cf8b (9fe4b1ad)][0m Deleting UiAutomator2 session
[38;5;171m[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@cf8b (9fe4b1ad)][0m Deleting UiAutomator2 server session
[38;5;171m[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@cf8b (9fe4b1ad)][0m Matched '/' to command name 'deleteSession'
[38;5;171m[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@cf8b (9fe4b1ad)][0m Proxying [DELETE /] to [DELETE http://127.0.0.1:8203/session/e5d0faab-8744-488e-8309-1362ea992f72] with no body
[38;5;171m[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@cf8b (9fe4b1ad)][0m Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"e5d0faab-8744-488e-8309-1362ea992f72","value":null}
[38;5;229m[ADB][0m Running 'C:\Users\sudha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s RZCWA1JJM5L shell dumpsys activity services io.appium.settings/.recorder.RecorderService'
[38;5;160m[Logcat][0m Stopping logcat capture
[38;5;229m[ADB][0m Removing forwarded port socket connection: 8203 
[38;5;229m[ADB][0m Running 'C:\Users\sudha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s RZCWA1JJM5L forward --remove tcp:8203'
[38;5;171m[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@cf8b (9fe4b1ad)][0m Restoring hidden api policy to the device default configuration
[38;5;229m[ADB][0m Running 'C:\Users\sudha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s RZCWA1JJM5L shell 'settings delete global hidden_api_policy_pre_p_apps;settings delete global hidden_api_policy_p_apps;settings delete global hidden_api_policy''
[38;5;83m[AppiumDriver@d5e5][0m Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1735375772420 (14:19:32 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[38;5;83m[AppiumDriver@d5e5][0m Encountered internal error running command: Error: No Chromedriver found that can automate Chrome '118.0.5993'. You could also try to enable automated chromedrivers download as a possible workaround.
    at Object.wrappedLogger.errorWithException (C:\Users\sudha\.appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-driver\node_modules\@appium\support\lib\logging.js:114:43)
    at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (C:\Users\sudha\.appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-driver\node_modules\@appium\support\lib\logging.js:120:16)
    at Chromedriver.start (C:\Users\sudha\.appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-driver\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\lib\chromedriver.js:695:16)
    at AndroidUiautomator2Driver.setupNewChromedriver (C:\Users\sudha\.appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-driver\node_modules\appium-android-driver\lib\commands\context\helpers.js:745:3)
    at AndroidUiautomator2Driver.startChromeSession (C:\Users\sudha\.appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-driver\node_modules\appium-android-driver\lib\commands\context\exports.js:346:23)
    at AndroidUiautomator2Driver.performSessionPostExecSetup (C:\Users\sudha\.appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-driver\lib\driver.ts:647:7)
    at AndroidUiautomator2Driver.startUiAutomator2Session (C:\Users\sudha\.appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-driver\lib\driver.ts:697:5)
    at AndroidUiautomator2Driver.createSession (C:\Users\sudha\.appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-driver\lib\driver.ts:419:22)
    at AppiumDriver.createSession (C:\Users\sudha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\lib\appium.js:740:35)
[38;5;86m[HTTP][0m [37m<-- POST /session [39m[31m500[39m [90m10616 ms - 862[39m [90m[39m
[38;5;74m[Instrumentation][0m .
[38;5;74m[Instrumentation][0m Time: 4.027

[38;5;74m[Instrumentation][0m 

[38;5;74m[Instrumentation][0m OK (1 test)
[38;5;74m[Instrumentation][0m The process has exited with code 0

